# Error using std::bind and std::function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, newtons-method, stdbind

I attempt to try my snippet of Newton's method on a multivariate function and used `std::bind` and `std::function`. But I was stuck on an error

> error: conversion from 'std::_Bind_helper&, int>::type {aka
>   std::_Bind, int))(double, double,
>   double)>}' to non-scalar type 'std::function'
>   requested

What does this error message mean and how should I fix my current code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<cmath>

double newton(std::function<double(double)> F, std::function<double(double)> f,
              double x=0, int maxiter=1000, double epsilon=0.001)
{
    int n = 0;
    while((n < maxiter) && (fabs(F(x)) > epsilon))
    {
        x = x - F(x) / f(x);
        n++;
    }
    return x;
}

// I'd like to fix x and z at 1 and 2 and find root for y
double ftest(double x, double y, double z) 
{
    return x * x + (y * y - 2 * y - 4) + z * z;
}

// Partial derivative of ftest with regards to y
double ftest1(double y) 
{
    return 2 * y - 2;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::function<double(double)> F = std::bind(ftest, 1, _2, 2);
    std::function<double(double)> f = ftest1;
    std::cout << newton(F, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_2` looks like it should be `_1`.  Second, have you considered not using `std::bind`, and just using a lambda?  `[](double y){ return ftest(1,y,2); }` looks cleaner than a `bind` to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here:

```
std::function<double(double)> F = std::bind(ftest, 1, _2, 2);
```

is that `F` is a function that takes a single argument of type `double`, but your bind expression involves `_2` - which refers to the second argument passed to the function object that `bind()` returns. That is, the *second* argument. Basically, you're constructing this function object, roughly:

```
struct {
    template <class T, class U>
    auto operator()(T, U arg) {
        return ftest(1, arg, 2);
    }
};
```

That object takes two arguments. `std::function<double(double)>` doesn't allow for that - it requires that your callable allow for a single argument.

The simple fix is to fix the placeholder:

```
std::function<double(double)> F = std::bind(ftest, 1, _1, 2);
```

or, better, just don't use `bind()` at all and prefer a lambda:

```
std::function<double(double)> F = [](double y) { return ftest(1, y, 2); }
```

Comment: Thanks, Barry. I wonder why lambda is preferable here.

Comment: @Nicholas Well, it took a SO question + some expert's C++ knowledge (or 5 minutes of my Google-foo ;) ) to get the bind thing to work. The lambda on the other hand is hard to get wrong.

Comment: @Nicholas bind is not really recommended. It's a very complicated and not very intuitive beast that was invented in the days before lambdas. If you want to dig into this topic I highly recommend this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0